# Regular expression that gets a variable length field and outputs a field that is fixed

Tags: php, regex, vbscript, output

I need to add an ID field to a plif file that is made from the user ID section of an email address. Our email user ID is a variable length but when I output that as an ID the output must be exactly 48 characters long. 
The regex that finds the email user ID

```
 A(02||20)(N.* )([^ ]*)(\@[a-zA_Z.]*newpaltz.edu)
```

The out put for email user ID I have so far \3 = email user ID & ZZZ was just a place holder so I could easily find my out put.

```
 A02\3 ZZZ A\1\2\3\4
```

The problem is I can't format the output to be exactly 48 characters long. 

Here are 3 email user  IDs I might get

```
toleveg
some.otheruser
n03468654
```

I would have to output them formatted like this:

```
A02toleveg             +                   00ACN
A02some.otheruser      +                   00ACN
A02n03468654           +                   00ACN
```

I have been using notepad++ but I think I may switch over to PHP. VBscript or Jscript are other languages I can cope with if there is no direct regular expression solution.

Comment: What are the new 33 chars and where should they be?  In between?

Comment: The other characters would not always be 33 characters. I added input and output examples above.

Comment: So there are spaces and then a plus sign midway between?  You'll need to show some PHP code for getting the address and concatenating the pieces.  `str_pad()` or `str_repeat()` may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have a working solution for my self but it is in the Note Tab Pro built in macro programming language. I have found Note Tab Pro invaluable over the years. so for what its worth here is my code.

```
Set Email ID as New User ID
    ^!Jump TEXT_START
    ^!Continue The PLIF File must be open in the active Window. This will make a user id field out of New Paltz email user ID if they have one.
    ^!set %count%=0
    ^!set %bannercount%=0
    ^!set %longones%=0
    ^!set %currentline%=0
    ^!set %longids%=""
    ^!set %numberoflines%=^$GetLineCount$
    ^!select ALL
    ^!Keyboard Ctrl+U
    ^!Replace "ANEWMN" >> "ANEW50" IASW 
    ^!Replace "A20N0" >> "A2080" TIAW 
    ^!Replace "NEWMNNEWMN00000000Y" >> "     NEWMN00000000Y" RIAW
    ;Replacements for second loader file
    ;^!Replace "A20N0([0-9]{7}[ ]+\+[ ]+)\d\dACN" >> "A0280$1\02ACN"  RWAS
    ^!Jump TEXT_START
    :findnext
    ^!find "( \d)(\d)(\d\d\d\dA16.+)( A)(02|20)(8[^ ]+)(.+ )([^ ]+)(\@[a-zA_Z.]*newpaltz.edu)" RAITS
    ^!IfError DONE
    ^!SetArray %Matches%=^$GetReSubStrings$
    ^!set %numofIDs%=^%Matches2%
    ^!set %email%=^%Matches8%
    ^!set %banner%=^%Matches6%
    ^!if ^$StrCopyRight(^%banner%;6)$=^$StrCopyRight(^%email%;6)$ usesbanner ELSE tryemail
    :usesbanner
    ^!inc %bannercount%
    ^!Jump LINE_END
    ^!set %newIDfield%=""
    ^!goto findnext
    :tryemail
    ^!set %emaillength%=^$StrSize(^%email%)$
    ^!if ^%emaillength% > 20 toobig ELSE doit
    :toobig
    ^!inc %longones%
    ^!set %longids%=^%longids%^P^%email%
    ^!Jump LINE_END
    ^!set %newIDfield%=""
    ^!goto findnext
    :doit
    ^!set %spaces%=^$Calc(20-^%emaillength%)$
    ^!set %newIDfield%=" A02^%email%^$StrRandom(^%spaces%; )$+                   02ACN                                                   "
    ^!Inc %count%
    ^!Inc %numofIDs%
    ^!StatusShow Don't touch Changing number ^%count%
    ^!InsertText ^%Matches1%^%numofIDs%^%Matches3%^%newIDfield%^%Matches4%^%Matches5%^%Matches6%^%Matches7%^%Matches8%^%Matches9%
    ^!Jump LINE_END
    ^!set %newIDfield%=""
    ^!goto findnext
    :DONE
    ^!Jump TEXT_START
    ^!Info [L]Added Campus IDs to ^%count% ^POut of ^%numberoflines% records^P^%bannercount% IDs = banner number alwready^P^P^%longones% IDs were too long: ^%longids%
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist using VBScript, you can use a callback function on the Replace method of the regular expression:

```
Set re = new RegExp
re.global = true
re.pattern = "A(02||20)(N.* )([^ ]*)(\@[a-zA_Z\.]*newpaltz.edu)"
myString = "A02Ntoleveg anyOtherText toleveg@bla.newpaltz.edu"
msgbox re.Replace(myString, getRef("replaceHelper"))

public function replaceHelper(match, fixed20or02, Nanything, emailLeft, emailRight, position, fullstring)
    Set sb = CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
    sb.Append_3 "A"
    sb.Append_3 fixed20or02
    sb.Append_3 left(emailLeft & string(48, " "), 48)
    sb.Append_3 "00ACN"

    replaceHelper = sb.ToString()
end function

' outputs: "A02toleveg                                         00ACN"
```

Note: I think it is not the exact output that you need, but you'll get the idea, it is easy to adapt to your wishes.
Note2: I used a stringbuilder for learns and funs, but you can still use `s = s & "text to append"` of course.
Note3: use a `\.` in the last group of your regular expression. `.` will just match everything.
Note4: Email validation is a difficult, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses). Be sure all addresses will match. (You can contact me at `my*account{"@possible spam"!}@[IPv6:2001:db8:1ff::a0b:dbd0]`)

Comment: Yes thank you I ended up setting the email id part as a variable getting it's length then subtracted that from the number of spaces available then used that number to repeat that number of spaces after it. But I did it in NoteTab Pros built in programing language which is unlike anything else so I'm not sure how valuable my code would be. I would love it if regular expression replacement output could gather properties like length and do a little math.